# How to sum elements based on their index range in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Imagine I have this data:

| start | end | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 100 |
| 2 | 4 | 200 |
| 1 | 2 | 600 |

start and end represent a range where this value is. I need to sum all the values based on their ranges.
Here is the idea:

```
100 100 100 100 100   <- because 100 is from index 0 to 5
+
0   0   200 200 0     <- because 200 is from index 2 to 4
+
0   600 0   0   0     <- because 600 is from index 1 to 2
=
100 700 300 300 100   <- summed result
```

I know, it is possible to achieve this behavior using a for loop, but if I have millions of rows, the performance is lacking. Is there a better solution, like using some kind of vectorization method?
I initially tried to solve it in numpy, but if there is any other technology out there that can help, please let me know.

Here is the code example using loops:

```
zeros = np.zeros(5)
data = np.array([
    [0, 5, 100],
    [2, 4, 200],
    [1, 2, 600]
])
start = data[:,0]
end= data[:,1]
values = data[:,2]
groups_length = len(start)
for i in range(groups_length):
    zeros[start[i]:end[i]] += values[i]
print(zeros)
```

Comment: As has been asked many times before in these 'eliminate loops' questions,  show the sample loop code.  It gets rid of potential ambiguities.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, my apologies, I have added the loop code now in description

Comment: what is the maximum value for end?

Comment: @mozway 2000 is the max value for end

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [0, 5, 100],
    [2, 4, 200],
    [1, 2, 600]
])

start = data[:, 0]
end = data[:, 1]
values = data[:, 2]

length = np.max(end) + 1

indices = np.arange(length)
mask = (indices >= start[:, None]) & (indices <= end[:, None])

result = np.sum(mask * values[:, None], axis=0)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[100 700 900 300 300 100]
```

Comment: the question is about how to do it without loops

Comment: @WorstEnemy, updated answer without loops by using advanced indexing and broadcasting in numpy

Comment: Where do you have advanced indexing?

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast the comparison and perform a dot product (shortcut to product and sum):

```
a = np.arange(df['end'].max())[:,None]

m = (df['start'].to_numpy() <= a) & (df['end'].to_numpy() > a)

out = m @ df['value']
```

Output: `array([100, 700, 300, 300, 100])`

Intermediates:

```
# a
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])

# m
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False]])
```